# How do I apply aspect ratio constraints to a custom UICollectionViewCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a grid style view that displays photo album covers. I would like 3 album covers per row. The tricky part is getting the cells to increase size appropriately depending on what device is being used e.g. iPhone 4s/5/5s/5c/6/6 plus, so that 3 items/cells are always shown per row no matter what device is being used.

I've never been able to do this. I was thinking about setting the sizes manually like so:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if DeviceHelper.DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        return CGSizeMake(115, 140)
    } else if DeviceHelper.DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        return //size
    } else if DeviceHelper.DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        return //size
    } else {
        return //size 
    }
}
```

I have a helper that determines what device is being used and I can call it from anywhere within my app. But isn't there a way to make sure 3 cells are always displayed in each row no matter what device is being used and also have equal padding shown to something like this:

[image]

The aspect ratio constraints have been helpful but this time round I can't apply them to the cell because interface builder won't allow it. Is there a straight forward to do this?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove default cell spacing :

[image: Remove cell spacing]

Try this code :

Just set value for `numberOfCellInRow` for number of cells in a row of collection view

### Obj-C

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   int numberOfCellInRow = 3;
   CGFloat padding = 5.0;
   CGFloat collectionCellWidth =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/numberOfCellInRow;
   CGFloat finalWidthWithPadding = collectionCellWidth - padding;
   return CGSizeMake(finalWidthWithPadding , finalWidthWithPadding);
}
```

### Swift

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var numberOfCellInRow : Int = 3
    var padding : Int = 5
    var collectionCellWidth : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(numberOfCellInRow)) - CGFloat(padding)
    return CGSize(width: collectionCellWidth , height: collectionCellWidth)
}
```

I think it will work for all the devices.

Comment: Just trying to convert this to swift.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There are 2 items per row with a big gap in the middle.

Comment: It's working now thanks. Can you modify the code to include padding please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77368/discussion-between-ashish-kakkad-and-londonguy).

Comment: missed vertical padding, and you assumed the collection view cell is a square. Isn't it OP is asking about keeping the aspect ratio of the cell?

Comment: OP needs that and Note that answer is accepted before many months.